# Intercepting option-close

Tags: macos, cocoa

Normally closing a window with option key down closes all the windows in the application.  In my application, I'd like it to close only windows related to the window that the user was closing.  How can I do that?  I can implement windowShouldClose for all my windows, but how can I know which window the user clicked on?

Comment: Look at NSWindow, NSWindowController and the delegate for NSWindow. Subclassing may help. Also you'll probably want to add something in your app delegate.

Comment: Also NSDocument and NSDocumentController, assuming your app is document-based.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

You can see if the option key was held down in the event that is being processed like this:

`([[NSApp currentEvent] modifierFlags] & NSAlternateKeyMask)!=0`

If this is in response to the user clicking the window's close button, then you can find the window that was clicked like this: `[[NSApp currentEvent] window]`

I suppose you should also check that `[NSApp currentEvent]` is a mouse event, etc., but it seems like this combination of tests should get you the info that you want.

---

If, on the other hand, this is the user choosing the "Close Window" command from the "File" menu with the option key held down, you can override the `performClose:` method from `NSWindow`s default implementation to your own, where you would do the `currentEvent` test above before calling `[super performClose: sender]`

Comment: I wouldn't check that `currentEvent` is a mouse event. The menu item might have been invoked via an accessibility tool (such as VoiceOver) or by a custom keyboard shortcut. If the action method to which the menu item is connected has been called, that is grounds enough.

Comment: Ah, I assumed the question was regarding the close button control at the upper left of the window itself. I guess option-clicking the Close Window menu item has the same effect.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to Cocoa.  How do I intercept the menu item action that is invoked for option-Close Window?  This is something that is provided by the system, it's not a menu item I define.  I need to intercept it before it goes and asks all the other windows to close.

Comment: @user2802999 - I edited the answer to include the menu item case.